# How can i Implement DateFilters with RadioButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve the Logic behind UI, Please explain how can i implement it with Flutter
For example, when I select This Week, it should be able to have a Date Filter that filters for this week and the rest

Thank  you

[image]

Am still yet to figure it out

Comment: Are you looking for the way to implementing this feature or flutter specific code to do that? If it's the later, can you show what code have you done so far?

Comment: yes am looking for a flutter specific code that can achieve this thank you

Comment: Use `DateTimeRange` for each radio button value and in a wapper stateful widget create a variable that holds the value of currentSelectedDateTimeRange and pass this variable as an argument to the radio buttons group value and on the selection of each radio button set state the currentSelectedDateTimeRange variable to new selected DateTimeRange